# c# error in program, bracket misplacement?

Tags: c#

I keep getting an error line 50 column 13 that "A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods"
Also line 47 column 17 "Expected catch or finally"
The code is to be a C# program in console mode to load the data file as a sequential file using C# System.IO library into an ArrayList data structure (using the System.Collection library) Store each line in the file as a separate record. Then the file is loaded into the ArrayList, sort the data in ascending order based on the LastName field and Display the following fields:Next, sort the data in descending order based on the ZIP field, and display the following fields: and finally Display all the records (and all its fields) for everyone that is in the state "NY."

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication24
{
class dataItem
{
    // this class will hold the data from one string in the file
    string FirstName;
    string LastName;
    // etc.
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // create a place to store our data
        ArrayList data = new ArrayList();

        // open and read a text file
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Unit4IP");

        try
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Unit4IP"))
            {
                // need a string to hold the fields and a string variable for each line of text.
                String line;
                string[] fields;

                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null);
                }
                    fields = line.Split(new Char [] {','});

                    Console.WriteLine(fields[0]);
                    Console.WriteLine(fields[1]);

            // from here you can create a data to store your fields in it
            // then insert the object into your data ArrayList.
            // after that, you can do the sorting and output after this loop is done reading
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);

        // Store text file contents in an appropriate data structure

        // Sort data

        // Output data

        // put this at the end to keep the console window from disappearing
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to continue..");
            Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: missing closing bracket `}` at the end from the look of it.

Comment: After Try => Using => While there are 4 closing brackets while you only have 2 opening brackets....

Comment: Select all your code in the window (ctrl-A) and then collapse it (ctrl-M-M, hit M twice while hold ctrl down). That way you'll see where's the missing bracket.

Answer (score 4):

This looks wrong:

```
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null);
                }
```

I'm guessing from the mismatch between indentation and braces that you don't want that semicolon, and that the closing curly brace is supposed to be an opening curly brace.  There may be other issues, but the first thing to do is check your braces against the indentation.